# Accessing variable in an ArrayList Object - Type class getter not working

Tags: java, class, inheritance, arraylist, types

I'm trying to learn a bit more about how ArrayList types work when using a custom class and have run into a problem I don't quite understand. I have the public get methods set in my type class, but can't get them to work when calling them for my ArrayList. Here are simplified versions of the classes:

```
public class ResultsEntry {

//Create instance private variables count (int) and target (char)
private Integer count;
private char target;

//Create a single constructor with the two values
public ResultsEntry (Integer count, char target)
{
    this.count = count;
    this.target = target;
}

//Public get methods for count and target
public Integer getCount()
{
    return count;
}

public char getTarget()
{
    return target;
}

//Public toString method that returns a string in the format <target, count>
public String toString() {
    return ("<" + target + ", " + count + ">");
}   
}
```

Then the next class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SharedResults {

//Create private instance variable - results (ArrayList of ResultsEntry type)

private static ArrayList<ResultsEntry> results = new ArrayList<ResultsEntry>();

//A default constructor that initializes the above data structure
public SharedResults (Integer resultsCount, char resultsTarget)
{
    Integer sharedResultsCount = resultsCount;
    char sharedResultsTarget = resultsTarget;
    results.add(new ResultsEntry(sharedResultsCount, sharedResultsTarget));
}

/* 
 * getResult method with no arguments returns sum of the count entry values in the  
 * shared results data structure. 
 */
public static Integer getResults()
{
    Integer sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("getResults method input "+ results.(i));
        Integer input = results.getCount(i);
        sum = input + sum;
        /*
         *Some code here that adds new count results to the counts in all
         *other array elements
        */
    }   
    return sum;
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `results.getCount(i);` gives an error that getCount is not defined for type `ArrayList<ResultsEntry>`.

My understanding was that the ArrayList would inherit the methods of the type's class. Any insight into what's happening here?

Comment: "My understanding was that the ArrayList would inherit the methods of the type's class" - you mean of your `ResultsEntry` class? No, absolutely not. I suspect you want `results.get(i).getCount()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. The `ArrayList` contains instances of `ResultsEntry`, I believe you want to get the element of `ResultsEntry` for a given index `i` and then invoke `getCount()` on that instance. Like,

```
int count = results.get(i).getCount();
```

And, if you're using Java 8+, your entire method could be replaced with a lambda, a map and a call to `sum`. Like

```
return results.stream().mapToInt(ResultsEntry::getCount).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You frist need to get the item from arraylist before you do

```
.getCount();
```

Otherwise how should the code know which item in the list you are targeting